# What kind of of java.lang.Error can be thrown during compile time?

Tags: java

What kind of java.lang.Error can be thrown during compile time ?
I know one error: `ClassFormatError`. What are the others error?
I'm writing an application that acts as a server. The server can compile a java program. During compilation I don't want to bring it down with any error, ensuring compilation. I have taken the necessarry steps that can prevent a compilation error.
I'm not sure with java.lang.Error, I can catch Throwable object and prevent it, but I need to know what are the error objects that can be thrown during compile time.

Comment: None. Exceptions, Errors, Throwables are not thrown at compile time. Your question doesn't make sense.

Comment: I seem to remember some case of generics with generic types or something causing infinite recursion in the compiler (which would cause a StackOverflowError or OutOfMemoryError, depending on whether the heap or stack space ran out first).  So a compile-time Error is possible, but it requires a broken compiler.  :)

Comment: @EJP classFormaError can thrown at compile time when method code length reaches the specifid limit

Comment: I got the compiler to throw an OutOfMemoryError by attempting to compile a class with a million `public static final` constants.

Comment: @anish - it might help to state which compiler you are using (Sun javac; Eclipse; etc) and how you are invoking it (separate process; [javax.tools](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/tools/package-summary.html); etc.)

Comment: @McDowell Thanks  i'm using javac and no ide is there the server is  standalone thread  is responsible for compiling the java program.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Errors thrown at compilation time (in the `javac`) occur when the compiler has an internal error.  You can provide valid java code and the compiler can die.  A common error I see is OutOfMemoryError when I compile a large code base but my IDE hasn't given the compiler enough memory (the default in my IDE is 128 MB)

ClassFormatError can occur when the compile tries to load a compiled class file which is corrupt.

You don't need to know all the error thrown, you can just catch Throwable.  They should only be the result of very unusual event which are likely to be unrecoverable. All you can do is log the error and prevent the thread from dying.